# Driver for internal LTE modem Dell Qualcomm Snapdragon X20 LTE (556-BCES) for Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, 22.04, modem

Trying to find drivers for internal LTE modem Dell Qualcomm Snapdragon X20 LTE (556-BCES) of Dell Latitude 7320 laptop (not detachable).

What already done:

1. Asked Dell support - they don't have one for nix systems
2. Asked Qualcomm support - they sent to Dell support)

In Dell supports they sent me win drivers for X20 LTE (556-BCES)

Googling didn't help....

Comment: Sorry, I have mistaken with tag, correct: 22.04

Comment: It should just work because supported at the kernel.